# Как последовательно связать три таблицы

Tags: php, yii2

Есть три таблицы County(id, name), Sity(id,name,country_id),Street(id,name,sity_id)

```
    Country          Sity                           Steet
 id   name          id   name    country_id      id   name   sity_id          
 1   Россия         1    Москва     1            1    Арбат    1
```

- Вопрос 1. Как мне, обращаясь через модель `Street` получить такую
  запись: Россия  г.Москва, ул. Арбат
- Вопрос 2. Как мне получить все
  Города и улицы этих городов обращаясь через модель `Country`. В просторах интернета и в документации встретил такой код:

  `public function getItems()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Item::className(),['id'=>'item_id'])->via('orderItems');
  }`

Не знаю подходит ли он мне и как с ним работать тоже не понял. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Правильно - city.

Comment: @АлексейУколов код не живой так для примера. То что вы написали разве важно ?

Comment: Напрямую к вопросу это, конечно, не относится, но я считаю, что это всё-таки важно. Это культура и чистота кода, а эти вещи напрямую виляют на то, сколько код проживёт.

Comment: @АлексейУколов я уже объяснил что это взятые с потолка примеры, Или передвами надо попросить прошения за то что я не так по английски написал слово город?

Comment: Вы объяснили и задали вопрос. Я на ваш вопрос ответил. Вам не кажется, что дискуссию пора прекратить? Я указал на ошибку, вы вправе проигнорировать мой комментарий, вправе попросить прощения - делайте что хотите, но не нужно меня в это втягивать.

Comment: @АлексейУколов  В том то и дело на вопрос вы не ответили. И да я согласен дискуссия прекращена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь всегда нужно читать [официальную документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table), ваш пример движется в верном направлении, но неправильный, в документации есть 2 способа:

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->viaTable('order_item', ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

или

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItems');
    }
}
```

То есть во втором примере, без функции `getOrderItems()` вы не сможете использовать `via()`.