# Связь таблиц в модели yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 3 таблицы (`order`, `order_delivery`, `order_types`). Для всех созданы модели, для `order` gridview. В таблице `order` есть колонка `order_number`, в таблице `order_delivery` колонки `order_number` и `order_delivery_code`, в таблице `order_types` колонки `delivery_types_code` и `delivery_types_name`. Я могу в модели Order создать функцию `public function getType(){
        return $this->hasOne(OrderDelivery::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
    }`  в индексе `'type.order_delivery_code'` и вывести коды доставок из `order_delivery`. Вопрос, как вместо кодов доставок вывести расшифровку из 3 таблицы `delivery_types_name`?

Upd. Сделал так.

`public function getType(){
    return $this->hasOne(DeliveryTypes::className(), ['delivery-types_code' => 'order_delivery_code'])
        ->viaTable('order_delivery', ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}` 
Всем спасибо за участие.

Comment: мне кажется вопрос очень похож на этот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520759/

Comment: @MasterAlex проясните пожалуйста по вашему ответу снизу

Comment: @MasterAlex уже второй день бьюсь на решением задачи(снизу). вы имеете ввиду создать переменную в модели `Order` или `OrderSearch`? покажите примерный код пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Не много не понятно в чем проблема, хочется найти какоето нативное решение что бы не джойнить таблички? Ну как вариант в каждой модели создать статический метод который на вход будет получать id а на выход расшифровку. Но я бы навероне на заморачивался а просто сделал метод в котором бы переджойнил требуемое. как то так

Сам виджет :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $model->getOrderDelivery(),
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'orderNumber' , 
            'deliveryTypesName'
         ]
     ]);
 ?>
```

Метод выборки и формирование `dataProvider`

```
public function getOrderDelivery(){

    //Получим поля , свяжем с типом
    $query = new Query();
    $query->select(['O.order_number orderNumber' , 
                    'OT.delivery_types_name deliveryTypesName'])
            ->from(['order O'])
            ->leftJoin('order_delivery OD', 'OD.order_number = O.order_number')
            ->leftJoin('order_types OT', 'OT.order_delivery_code = OD.order_delivery_code ');

    //получим provider для GridView
    $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 50,
            ],
            'sort' => ['attributes' => ['orderNumber', 'deliveryTypesName']],
    ]);
    return $provider;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Данный вопрос легко решается через [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#declaring-relations):

**Модель Order.php**

```
public function getDelivery(){
    return $this->hasOne(OrderDelivery::className(), ['order_number' => 'order_number']);
}
```

**Модель OrderDelivery.php**

```
public function getType(){
    return $this->hasOne(OrderTypes::className(), ['delivery_types_code' => 'order_delivery_code']);
}
```

Далее при подгрузке модели Order во view, вы может получить `delivery_types_name` c помощью такой переменной:

```
$model->delivery->type->delivery_types_name
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, `$model->delivery->type->delivery_types_name` прописывается в `'columns' => [`?

Comment: @cruim, нет, данный вывод информации не будет работать через GridView, для этого нужно создать в моделе отдельное поле, которому присвоить значение